# Bash auto-completion won't work for java command

Tags: bash, java, auto-completion

I have a folder that has one java source (.java) and one java (.class) class file. I try to get the autocomplete functionality of bash by pressing <*tab*> after the

```
java
```

or

```
java MyCl
```

in order for bash to auto fill the filename *MyClass* .

Nothing happens though...

**INFO**:

My java file is located in

```
which java
/home/username/Programs/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
```

and

```
whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Comment: Are you sure you're in the same directory as the `MyClass.java`/`MyClass.class` file? Just asking the stupid question because you'd be surprised how often stupid things cause problems.

Comment: Absolutely sure !

Answer (score 0):

set your CLASSPATH variable to include the current directory. 
For example, in your ~/.bashrc (or ~/.profile) add this line:

```
    export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH
```